# R - values above the scale

Tags: r, plot, r-sp

I'm plotting a rain map for a region. My problem is that when a temperature is above the established scale, some white points are plotted.

function:

```
spplot(
datavalue, 
main        = list(label=main,cex=0.9), 
sp.layout   = layout.list.compl(shapeBound,shapeSurround,complete=TRUE,0.45),
xlim        = xlim,
ylim        = ylim,
col.regions = color,
at          = c(0,10,20,30,50,70,90,110,130,150,170,190,210,230),
colorkey    = list(
  labels=list(
    at     = labelat,
    labels = c("0","10","20","30","50","70","90","110","130","150","170","190","210","230")
  )
),
scales      = list(draw=TRUE), 
pretty      = TRUE,
cex         = 10
)
```

Is there some kind of dynamic range in spplot function?

Map:

[image]

Comment: Maybe those are NA? Without the data it's difficult to test any theories.

Comment: can't you build your scale based on the raster data? grab the data and `cut` it to your `breaks`. Could you provide the data and complete code used to build this plot?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `sp::spplot` takes the data range as default range for the color scale.

In your example (which does not reveal what `labelat` refers to), you could replace the maximum value (230) with the data maximum, `max(datavalues[[1]])`, or if you want to keep it to 230 at the minimum, replace it with `max(c(230, datavalues[[1]]))`. Also set the right value in the `labels`, otherwise it doesn't make sense.